# Pass on an event from encapsulated class

Tags: c#, events, encapsulation

If I have a class A which encapsulates a class B instance, is it possible to pass on through an instance of class A an event which was raised in class B? For example:

```
public classB
{
    ...
    public event EventArgs SomeEvent;
    protected virtual void OnSomeEvent(EventArgs e)
    ...
}

public classA
{
    ...
    private classB = new ClassB();
    ...
}
```

What I would like happen is for any instance of class A to also expose SomeEvent such that when it is raised by class B that it is raised by class A?

Please can someone offer assistance or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to delegate the event to the original class:

```
public class ClassA
{
    private ClassB classB = new ClassB();
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent
    {
        add
        {
            classB.SomeEvent += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            classB.SomeEvent -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

That means when the event is raised in `ClassB`, all subscribers to `ClassA.SomeEvent` will also be notified because they are - in fact - subscribed to `ClassB.SomeEvent`. I'm not sure if that is going to be what you really want, but in any case, you can always use subscribe-and-raise method.

There's a catch here though: the `sender` object will be an instance of `ClassB`, not `ClassA`, which means that you can't delegate the event in, for example, WPF with `INotifyDataErrorInfo` validation, where the view model itself is expected to be raising the validation event. Then you just have to subscribe-and-raise.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing like [routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for simple classes. You should subscribe to ClassB event and raise event from ClassA when classB raises event:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent = (s,e) => { };
    private ClassB classB = new ClassB();

    public ClassA()
    {
       classB.SomeEvent += (s,e) => SomeEvent(this, e);
    }    
}
```

More classic way:

```
public ClassA
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
    private ClassB classB = new ClassB();

    public ClassA()
    {
       classB.SomeEvent += ClassB_SomeEvent;
    }

    private void ClassB_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SomeEvent != null)
            SomeEvent(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is very valuable information.